# .htaccess to modify an URL folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL of my web page like **`www.MyWeb.com/country/america/1`**
I want to convert it to **`www.MyWeb.com/america/1`**, Using ***.htaccess***.

in the url Country is a folder and the "1" is a PHP file that the extension .php was previously changed using .htaccess.

**How Can i do this ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MyWeb\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /country/$1
```

This basically redirects/rewrites every request to `www.MyWeb.com/` to `www.MyWeb.com/country/`
The same way you got rid of `.php` extension.